# Getting error while debuging php program in eclipse

Tags: php

I installed eclipse to make modification to my php file but when i write small php program in eclipse and when i try to run this i'm getting the following error

Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
7/20/2011 11:59:09 AM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

can any1 help me on this

Comment: its irrelevant what editor you are using

Answer (score 0):

You already have your answer:

> Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If
>   you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try
>   again.

Verify where your file is and the URL you are using to access it. If you are using mod_rewrite verify your rules.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about editor. Be sure where is your www root folder. First create there simple HTML `index.html` with notepad or whatever and chek if it's work on http://localhost/index.html.

Then save your script in Eclipse exactly where working index.html is. (remove it to prevent runing index.html instead of your script.

Maybe you have but project configuration and you try to run it from IDE ? se project configuration for something like 'run environment'